# Apple Music - Some sounds from Album are not available to download or listen

Tags: macos, itunes, mac, icloud, apple-music

I have Apple Music 3 month free trial and I added an album to my iCloud Music Library. But one sound is "disabled" and I cannot listen or download it. What's wrong?[image]

Comment: I get this on some albums too. I find that removing and re-adding will sometimes help. It seems like a bug?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what the reason is behind this, or if it's a bug. But generally I've had this occur when I either previously owned that song or uploaded it, or if I downloaded that song as a single (I.e. Free single of the week, etc.).

Either way, removing the entire album and any duplicate versions of that song, and then re-adding the album usually fix it for me. Best of luck!